# @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.6.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on react-native app, i couldn't able to connect firebase with react-native.

```
 @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.6.3): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

please someone help me on this issue.

Comment: can you share a piece of code from where the bug happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```js
// firebase-config.js
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const db = getFirestore(app);
```

to

```js
// firebase-config.js
import { initializeFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const database = initializeFirestore(app, {
  experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: true
})
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Now i got cleared by changing the config file , varies from react.